using sass to choose last randomly generated element even if nested
trying to get sass to choose the last button that's rendered.
i have a page with 3 of these p-elements that might, or might not, have a print button in them. and i need the last button to be yellow using sass. How do i select that if I don't know exactly know the structure ahead of time? Even if there is multiple print buttons, I can only make the last one yellow.
html
<p>
    <!-- <button class="print"></button> -->
</P>
<p>
    <!-- <button class="print"></button> -->
</P>
<p>
    <!-- <button class="print"></button> -->
</P>


Is there a guarantee that only the last p-tag is always empty? Even if not, it's easy to use javascript to apply the style only to the last button.

How is the button generated? It would be simpler if you could use whatever tool you also use to generate the output, and implement some logic that adds a class to the <p> or button, and use that class for your desired styling.

no guarantee of that Nine.
I don't have control of it Sigurd. There's some third-party angular stuff being imported in that I can only style passively with CSS/SASS. Pretty limiting situation. Not a huge fan of how it's been encoded and I've been told not to mess with it.

This can be done in pure CSS.
This snippet selects those p elements that have a button with a print class but have no following siblings which also have a button with the print class.
 p:has(button.print):not(:has(~p button.print))



<style>
  p {
    /* these setting are just for demo */
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lightgray;
  }
  
  p:has(button.print):not(:has(~p button.print)) {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
</style>
<div>NONE HAS print
  <p>
    <!--<button class="print"></button>-->
  </p>
  <p>
    <!--<button class="print"></button>-->
  </P>
  <p>
    <!--<button class="print"></button>-->
  </P>
</div>
<div>FIRST ONE ONLY HAS print
  <p>
    <button class="print"></button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <!--<button class="print"></button>-->
  </P>
  <p>
    <!--<button class="print"></button>-->
  </P>
</div>
<div>FIRST AND SECOND HAVE PRINT
  <p>
    <button class="print"></button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button class="print"></button>
  </P>
  <p>
    <!--<button class="print"></button>-->
  </P>
</div>
<div>ALL THREE HAVE PRINT
  <p>
    <button class="print"></button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button class="print"></button>
  </P>
  <p>
    <button class="print"></button>
  </P>
</div>




I tried it because I thought it would work, but it didn't work. p:has(+ p:not(:has(button.print)))... your solution works well. I learned it. Thank you :)


means 'immediately following sibling' while ~ means 'any following sibling'

